# Custom text font inside a Simplecursoradaptor

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, typeface, custom-font

I have made an application where i use a SimpleCursoradapter.

```
    String[] from = new String[] {"title","notes","image"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.esodaTextView, R.id.amountTextView, R.id.imageView1}; 
    esodaAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.recipe_list_item, null, from, to);
```

As you can see i show the three data at 2 TextViews (esodaTextView + amountTextView) and at one imageView.

**The question is how can i set a custom font (that is saved at assets folder) to these 2 TextViews (esodaTextView + amountTextView) so i can show text with the custom font.**

This is the xml file for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="#55eee9e9" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/esodaTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/esodaTextView"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:textSize="12dp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know that i can programmatically set a custom font via the following code but how can i use it inside a Simplecursoradaptor?

```
 TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "segoescb.ttf");  
 txt1.setTypeface(font);
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is overwrite the SimpleCursorAdapter's [ViewBinding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html):

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binding=adapter.setViewBinder( new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()
  {
    boolean SetViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
    {
      TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.iesodaTextView)
      //Do what you want here
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: At the code line: "TextView tv=view.findViewById(R.id.iesodaTextView);" i get an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to TextView

Comment: Fixed, just need to typecast the output from `findViewById`.

Comment: Now i do not get an error message but... text is not showing with the new font... I added "return true;" at your code.