# Changing Font of a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, fonts

I've built a ListView with a cursor adapter and I can change the font around it but not the font of the text in the ListView, here's the ListView code;

```
private void populate(){
    String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyname");
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getRow(email);
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_CPOINTS,DBAdapter.KEY_CNAME, DBAdapter.KEY_CLOC};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.textViewItemNumber, R.id.textViewItemTask, R.id.location};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

This is what I use to change font;

```
TextView list = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "VarelaRound-Regular.otf");
        myList.setTypeface(face);
```

I can't seem to get this working for the ListView?

Comment: A search on `cursoradapter font` on a major search engine turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541043/custom-text-font-inside-a-simplecursoradaptor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713513/how-to-use-custom-font-in-simplecursoradapter-for-a-list-view-at-searchable-dict and http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-how-to-use-a-custom-font/ and many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your own `TextView` that uses that font, or you will need to set the font to each item inside the `CursorAdapter`.

I would recommend the first approach; `extends` `TextView` and make it use the specific `TypeFace` you want.